# ¿Recibe un nombre particular la "sorpresita" del Roscón de Reyes?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

¿Recibe un nombre particular la "sorpresita" del Roscón de Reyes? En mi casa (y en mi familia cercana) siempre la hemos llamado "sorpresa" o "figurita", porque siempre era una figurita de algún tipo. A veces un muñequito y en contadas ocasiones algún otro tipo de regalito que no era una figurita.

Era una "sorpresa" porque no sabías lo que iba a ser. Tampoco sabías exactamente dónde iba a estar, pero sabías que en el roscón había, por lo menos, una. Y era algo bueno que te tocase.

Sin embargo recuerdo que algunos compañeros del colegio me decían que en sus roscones no había "figurita", sino un "haba" y si te tocaba era algo malo, porque te tocaba pagar el roscón.

Sea "haba" o "figurita", ¿recibe algún nombre específico el objeto dentro del Roscón de Reyes?

Answer (score 5):

En los roscones que compramos nosotros (zona de Sevilla y Cádiz, España) los roscones suelen llevar ambas figuras: la sorpresa y el haba. Los roscones suelen venir además con una corona, que se la pone aquel al que le toca la sorpresa. Y al que le toca el haba, efectivamente le toca pagar el roscón (cosa que al final nunca pasa en realidad, sobre todo porque le suele tocar a algún niño que son quienes más roscón comen).

No tengo entendido que se le dé un nombre especial a la sorpresa, nosotros siempre la hemos llamado así (o tal vez *premio*). Y tampoco encuentro nada en el [DIRAE](http://dirae.es) al respecto. En la Wikipedia también [se refieren](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosc%C3%B3n_de_Reyes) a la figurita como "sorpresa".

Ya como nota, no siempre los roscones llevan una figurita. Sé que hay algunas pastelerías que, por ejemplo, en algunos roscones cambian la figurita por un billete de X euros para incentivar la compra. Eso sí que es una *sorpresa*.

Comment: Un poco off-topic pero en saberia.com/2009/11/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-palabra-tontolab‌​a indican: "Utilizamos ‘tontolaba’ para referirnos coloquialmente a una persona ignorante, abobada, palurda y/o de cortas entendederas. Pero, ¿cuál es el origen de esta palabra? Pues bien, “tontolaba” es el apócope de ‘tonto del haba’, expresión que deriva de la tradición de poner en los roscones de reyes un regalo y un haba. Se supone que al que le tocaba el regalo le coronaban rey de la fiesta, mientras que el que encontraba el haba tenía el dudoso honor de pagar el dulce."

Answer (score 3):

En México se llama **muñeco** o **muñequito**. Aquí todas las panaderías ponen muñequito a sus roscas. Casi siempre es más de uno. El muñequito, la mayoría de las veces, representa al niño Jesús pero no es raro encontrar a los tres reyes magos con Jesús y María.

En México tampoco quieres que te salga el muñequito debido a que el *afortunado* debe cooperar con los tamales del día de la candelaria (2 de febrero). En realidad no hay que organizar una fiesta en sí. La mayor parte de las veces, el convivio es en la escuela o el lugar de trabajo. Además, debido a que casi siempre hay varios muñequitos, el gasto se distribuye entre varias personas.

---

También hay panaderías que sustituyen el muñeco por algún artículo de valor; por ejemplo un muñeco de oro o algo similar.

Comment: _Convivio_, nunca había oído esta palabra. ¿Qué quiere decir exactamente?

Comment: Un convivio es una celebración o reunión informal.

Answer (score 1):

Tradicionalmente la sorpresita solía ser la figurita de un bebé.  La razón es clara: la rosca de reyes celebra la visita de los Reyes Magos al niño Jesús (Mateo 2), y la figurita del bebé representa al bebé Jesús.  Quizas el reemplazo de la figurita de bebé con otras figuras u otras cosas (como los billetes de euro) sea un signo del reemplazo de la Cristianidad en la cultura hispanohablante por el secularismo; o quizas sea un signo de la popularidad de "Santa Claus", que ciertamente está reemplazando a los Reyes Magos como proveedor de juguetes (en el 25 de diciembre en lugar del 6 de enero).  La "sorpresa" no tiene un nombre general.  El nombre tradicional que se le da a la figura del bebé es "Niño Jesús".

Mis memorias de mi niñez en México me indican que la persona que encontrara al bebé Jesús tenía la responsabilidad de hacer la siguiente fiesta en el Día de la candelaria (el 2 de febrero) --- 40 dias despues de la Navidad --- cuándo se celebra la presentación del ninõ Jesús en el templo (y la purificación de la Virgen María).  Quizas por esta razón se empezó a pensar que era mala suerte encontrar al bebé Jesús --- ¿quién tiene tiempo o dinero para planear una fiesta estos días? --- y quizas también por esta razón se empezaron a poner dos "regalitos" en la rosca --- ¿quién quiere decir que el Niño Dios es "mala suerte"?

Comment: Gracias, pero, recibe un nombre particular? Esta información es interesante, pero no responde realmente a la pregunta.